# Magento2 - Custom Product Collection with Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2

I am trying to display  Layered Navigation Block  on custom page with custom product list.

For now i have custom controller, xml layout and template for product list.

1. What do i need to insert into xml layout to display layered navigation block ?

`<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
   <!-- ??? --> 
 </referenceContainer>`

2. How can i set custom product collection  (filtered by attribute e.g. 'book' == 1)  and use it  (with layered navigation)  on custom page  (e.g.  book list with author filter) ?

Answer (score 1):

The XML you need can be found in Magento/LayeredNavigation/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml

The snippet you'll need to add to your referenceContainer is:

```
<block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
</block>
```

I would suggest using a plugin to modify the render method of "Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" if you want to set a default filter.

Comment: That is exactly what i needed... **Thanks a lot!!!!** I can't understand why @kaspi didn't vote your answer...

Comment: But the results are not related to the custom product collection...